# Block HTTP POST Request if a record already exists in the database

Tags: java, mysql, ajax, jersey

I am developing a Java Rest web service to store user data in a MYSQL database.

When I test try POST with curl, I get

> 204 - No Content

on the client side and

`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'vinayUserName' for key 'name_UNIQUE'`

on the server side.

How can I program web service to handle 409 conflict for unique data in database and communicate the message to the client?

I am using Jersey to develop Web service and Jquery ajax on the client side to POST the data. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You should handle the SQL Exception and re-throw as Business Validation Exception Message.

Comment: Thanks, The idea in my mind is once the data from the client is deserialized, it has to be tested if it already exits in the database. If it doest exit, There should be some alert mechanism to notify the client. Even though I handle the SQL Exception, how can I pass a response back to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle SQLException ,Runtime Exception and Exception, then update webservice response with Corresponding Error Message as the parameter(Status - 'Sucess/Failure', ErrorMessage - 'Reason for Failure').

In the jquery extract the value from the parameters and display it to user.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37727/Prepare-a-JSON-Web-Service-and-access-it-with-JQue  --- Kindly have a look to get an idea..

Comment: Sure, Thanks for the immediate response.